# Trouble understanding a geometry problem involving triangle and bisector.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

**Problem Statement:**

> Suppose the straight line $AB$ of $\triangle ABC$ is bisected at $C$ and the perpendiculars $AX$, $BY$, $CZ$ are drawn to any straight line $OP.$ Prove that:
>
> i) if $A$, $B$ are on the same side of $OP,$ then $2CZ = AX + BY.$
>
> ii) if $A$, $B$ are on the opposite sides of $OP,$ then $2CZ =$difference of $AX$ and $BY$.

[*from pg. 74, question number 21. in [Challenge and Thrill of Pre-College Mathematics](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=SnvBeodeTDcC&printsec=frontcover&hl=de#v=onepage&q&f=false)*]

How can $C$ be a vertex of $\triangle ABC$ and
also where the side $AB$ of the triangle is bisected?

I think it might be a typo in the question. Assuming that they meant $O$ instead of $C$ as the bisector of $AB$, is there any case when the points $A$ and $B$ lie on the same side of a line drawn through their bisector (as specified in (i))?

I have searched elsewhere and in my books as well without much luck, so any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

Oops, (ii) should be 'opposite sides' not 'same side'. Also yeah, I find the wording confusing. In the degenerate case, if I take $OP \parallel AB$ both $A$ and $B$ lie on the same side of $OP$ then the perpendiculars $AX$, $BY$, $CZ$ have the same length so $2CZ = AX + BY$. So that's case (i).

For case (ii), if I take $OP$ through $C$ then $CZ$ = 0 and then if I prove that $\triangle ACX \cong \triangle BCY$ I can say that $AX = BY \implies 2CZ = AX - BY = 0.$

But I am not sure how to go about proving (ii) in general for 'any straight line $OP.$'

Comment: That's terrible wording, but I guess they simply mean that $\triangle ABC$ is a degenerate triangle, and $C$ is actually the midpoint of segment $AB$.

Comment: However, the obvious typo is that both questions ask to prove different things when A, B are on the same side of OP.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: AB of △ABC is bisected at C could also mean △ABC is isosceles at C. Just tried part i) and it cab be proved.

Comment: @Gray_Rhino No, that doesn't work. Suppose you take $OP \parallel AB$ so that $C$ and $OP$ are on opposite sides of $AB$, then $CZ \gt AX = BY$ so it is not possible that $2\, CZ=AX+BY$.

Comment: @dxiv Yes, good point. In that case, as you pointed out, C should be the midpoint of AB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @dxiv pointed out in the comment, the statement means $C$ is midpoint of $AB$. In that case part i) becomes trivial.

For part ii) when $OP$ does not pass through $C$ we can use similarity to prove the statement. Note that the question is asking the "difference of $AX$ and $BY$", this means absolute value of the difference as you can see below.

Suppose, $OP$ passes through $AC$ at $M$. We have triangles $AMX$, $CMZ$, and $BMY$ all similar to each other. By similarity $$\frac{AX}{CZ}=\frac{AC-MC}{MC}, \frac{BY}{CZ}=\frac{BC+MC}{MC}$$

Since $AC=BC$, subtracting the two we get the result.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks